# Avoid `exit 1` in bash script closing ssh session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm running a number of scripts which often include an exit clause if the preceding commands fail, e.g.:

```
[ ! -d $somefile ] && exit 1;
```

However, I'm running this through an ssh session, and if one of these exits are executed I'm kicked out of the ssh session. Is there a way to run a script but capture any exit commands to avoid it closing the ssh connection? Changing all the scripts is not an ideal option.

Comment: Unless you `source` those scripts, this should not be happening.  ... Unless your interactive shell is running with `set -e`?

Comment: @tripleee The script is probably being run in place of the default command (`ssh you@host some_script.sh`).

Comment: @chepner But then what would "avoid closing the ssh connection" mean here?  `ssh you@host 'some_script.sh || bash -i'`?

Comment: That's what I was imagining. Run the script, but drop into a remote shell for debugging/triage if the script fails.

Comment: @jodles Presumably, the script exits for a reason. Simply continuing the script wouldn't be a realistic option, so I suspect tripleee's suggestion is close to what you want.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed, set -e was the culprit! Thank you! I also hadn't thought of 'some_script.sh || bash -i', so thanks for that too.

Comment: @chepner Yes indeed you're right. The script failing is fine, but remaining in the shell is nice to debug, rather than ssh++ all over again to get back to where I was..

Answer (score 0):

You use [ssh session](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-to-connect-to-remote-server-linux-or-windows). If you just write

```
exit 1
```

then your current ssh session will be [finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195796/writing-a-bash-script-how-do-i-stop-my-session-from-exiting-when-my-script-exit).

To avoid finish use [-c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144514/add-arguments-to-bash-c)

```
bash -c "exit 1"
```