# Writing a bash script, how do I stop my session from exiting when my script exits?

Tags: bash

bash scripting noob here. I've found this article: https://www.shellhacks.com/print-usage-exit-if-arguments-not-provided/ that suggests putting
`[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 argument"; exit 1; }`

at the top of a script to ensure arguments are passed. Seems sensible.

However, when I do that and test that that line does indeed work (by running the script without supplying any arguments: `. myscript.sh`) then the script does indeed exit but so does the bash session that I was calling the script from. This is very irritating.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. Can anyone put me straight?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are doing. I guess that you run that line in your shell which was started as part of the session, and when it hits `exit 1` that shell is closed.

Comment: Yes I think you're right, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`. myscript.sh` is a synonym for `source myscript.sh`, which runs the script *in the current shell* (rather than as a separate process). So `exit` terminates your current shell. (`return`, on the other hand, wouldn't; it has special behaviour for `source`d scripts.)

Use `./myscript.sh` to run it "the normal way" instead. If that gives you a permission error, make it executable first, using `chmod a+x myscript.sh`. To inform the kernel that your script should be run with `bash` (rather than `/bin/sh`), add the following as the *very first line* in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

You can also use `bash myscript.sh` if you can't make it executable, but this is slightly more error-prone (somebody might do `sh myscript.sh` instead).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Thomas.

Comment: Well, the other obvious alternative is `bash myscript.sh`, which doesn't require executable bit or hashbang line.

Comment: Note that if your script *does* need to be executed with `source`, you can use `return` instead of `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

Question seems not clear if you're sourcing script `source script_name` or `. script_name` it's interpreted in current bash process, if you're running a function it's the same it's running in same process, otherwise, calling a script, caller bash forks a new bash process and waits until it terminates (so running `exit` doesn't exit caller process), but when running `exit` builtin in in current bash it exits current process.